# Node.js like API design principles and workflow

Tags: node.js, api-design

I'm designing and implementing an API for Node.js to access from Ubuntu an IBM mainframe via IBM3270 protocol using [x3270 tool](http://x3270.bgp.nu/). So Node.js process `spawn` `s3270` process and uses its `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to communicate with an IBM mainframe.

I've implemented the following interface:

```
var hs = require('./hs');

var session = hs.createSession(opts);

session.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('ERROR: %s', err.message);
});

session.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('** connected');
  session.send('TRANS');
});

session.on('response', function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  session.disconnect();
});

session.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('** disconnected');
  session.close();
});

session.on('close', function() {
  console.log('** closed');
});

session.connect();
```

Everything is working very well.

The problem is the following. I would like to use [Q promise library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) to get the client code that uses my API more organized, and also have Node.js like API in form of `session.send(trans, cb(err, res) {})`. **I don't realize how should I implement the `send` function in a manner that it accepts a callback**.

Generalizing my question I would like to know designing Node.js like API what should I implement first:

- simple `send(trans)` function that emits events and using this then implement `send('trans', cb(err, res) {})` OR
- implement `send('trans', cb(err, res) {})` first (I don't know how) and then implement events OR
- **how is the correct way to implement Node.js like API**

What I'm looking for is the **general workflow and design principles when designing Node.js like API** that could be also consumed by Q promise library.

Comment: It may not fully answer your question, but look at Q's `denodeify` function. It can consume any callback based function and convert it into its equivalent promise based function.

Comment: `Q.denodeify` or `Q.nfbind` creates a promise from Node.js style function: `send(trans, cb(err, res) {})`. The point is how to implement `send` function that accepts callback using `send(trans)` and events described in the main question code listing. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do exactly the same thing here, but I'm struggling to get started! Would you mind sharing some samples of your code please.

Comment: Sorry so late response. The working sample file is quite large to paste it here. If you are still interested in the working sample code send me an email.

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrProkopyuk, would you mind sharing some code with me as well?

Answer (score 0):

As I realized there are two approaches to design async API for Node.js:

- **callback-based** that could be implemented with `EventEmitter`
- **promise-based** that could be implemented with `var d = Q.defer();`, `return d.promise;` and `d.resolve();` from [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

I implemented my API with promise-based approach using Q library only in order to get my code more organized. Furthermore Q library has functions such as `Q.nfcall();`, `Q.nfapply();` and `Q.nfbind();` to convert callback-based Node.js API to promise-based equivalent.